# Why is timer0 the fastest timer in the arduino?

Tags: pwm, timers

In the [documentation](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/TimerPWMCheatsheet), it shows that the higher  frequency that can be reached with an Arduino UNO for and 8bits PWM is using timer0  with the pre-scaler  set at 1. That  gives a Fs of 62500 Hz, but why is that so?

I understand the Prescaler is dividing the frequency, but why it does start at 62500 Hz and  timer1 and timer2 have as maximum 31372 Hz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Timers 1 and 2 are configured by the Arduino core library to run the so
called “*phase correct PWM*” mode. In this mode, the timers count
forward from 0 to 255, and then they count backwards to zero. Timer 0 is
configured by the same library in “*fast PWM*” mode, where it counts
from 0 to 255 and then overflows back to zero in a single timer cycle.

You can, if you want, configure timers 1 and 2 in fast PWM mode. For
doing this, you will have to access their I/O registers directly. C.f.
the datasheet of the relevant microcontroller for details.

A couple of links:

- the [datasheet of the
  ATmega328P](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet_Complete.pdf)
  microcontroller describes all the possible configurations of the
  timers (sections 15, 16 and 18 for timer 0, 1 and 2, respectively)
- the source code of the [Arduino init()
  function](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/wiring.c#L284)
  to see how Arduino core configures them.

Comment: Where is that function called? is it in the bootloader?

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez: No, `init()` is [called by `main()`](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/main.cpp#L35).